# conditional rolling difference or gradient based on a column in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, gradient

I need to get the gradient of a column based on the conditional value of another column in a very large data.table.

```
> require(data.table)
> DT = data.table( ID = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 6)),
                   Condition = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                   Value = c(4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3))
```

I'd like to get the rolling gradient of the 'Value' column by ID, only for rows for which Condition == 1.

```
> desired_output
    ID Condition Value Gradient
 1:  A         0     4       NA    # condition isn't met so no gradient
 2:  A         1     3        0    # condition is met but there is no predecessor. Gradient set to 0
 3:  A         0     2       NA    # condition isn't met so no gradient
 4:  A         0     1       NA    # condition isn't met so no gradient
 5:  A         1     4        1    # condition is met and gradient is 4-3=1
 6:  A         1     3       -1    # condition is met and gradient is 3-4=-1
 7:  A         0     2       NA    # condition isn't met so no gradient
 8:  A         1     1       -2    # condition is met and gradient is 1-3=-2
 9:  B         0     4       NA
10:  B         0     3       NA
11:  B         1     2        0
12:  B         0     1       NA
13:  B         0     4       NA
14:  B         1     3        1
```

If possible I'd prefer a native data.table solution.

Please note: it's possible to do this by sub-setting DT[Condition == 1] and then rejoining the results. I'd like to avoid sub-setting and rejoining if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
dt = data.table( ID = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 6)),
                 Condition = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                 Value = c(4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3))

# 1
dt[Condition == 1, Gradient := Value - shift(Value, fill = first(Value)), by = ID][]
#>     ID Condition Value Gradient
#>  1:  A         0     4       NA
#>  2:  A         1     3        0
#>  3:  A         0     2       NA
#>  4:  A         0     1       NA
#>  5:  A         1     4        1
#>  6:  A         1     3       -1
#>  7:  A         0     2       NA
#>  8:  A         1     1       -2
#>  9:  B         0     4       NA
#> 10:  B         0     3       NA
#> 11:  B         1     2        0
#> 12:  B         0     1       NA
#> 13:  B         0     4       NA
#> 14:  B         1     3        1

#2
dt$grad <- c (NA, NA, -1, -2,1, -1, - 1, -2, NA, NA, NA, -1,2,1)

dt[Condition == 1, Value2 := Value, by = ID] %>% 
  .[, Value2 := shift(nafill(Value2, "locf"))] %>% 
  .[ Value2 != 1, Gradient2 := Value - Value2] %>% 
  .[, Value2 := NULL] %>% 
  .[]
#>     ID Condition Value Gradient grad Gradient2
#>  1:  A         0     4       NA   NA        NA
#>  2:  A         1     3        0   NA        NA
#>  3:  A         0     2       NA   -1        -1
#>  4:  A         0     1       NA   -2        -2
#>  5:  A         1     4        1    1         1
#>  6:  A         1     3       -1   -1        -1
#>  7:  A         0     2       NA   -1        -1
#>  8:  A         1     1       -2   -2        -2
#>  9:  B         0     4       NA   NA        NA
#> 10:  B         0     3       NA   NA        NA
#> 11:  B         1     2        0   NA        NA
#> 12:  B         0     1       NA   -1        -1
#> 13:  B         0     4       NA    2         2
#> 14:  B         1     3        1    1         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I didn't realise i can use Condition == 1 as filter and it automatically filters out everything else for gradient calculation. Silly me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. I myself only recently learned about this "data.table" feature.

Comment: There is another conditional case, which is a bit more complex. I should probably create a separate question. What if I would like to have the gradient for Value for every row (by ID), from the Value of the last row where Conditition == 1? meaning that gradient of each row would be always from the value of the last row which had Condition == 1. In that case the Gradient column output would be c(NA,NA,-1,-2,1,-1,-1,-2, NA,NA,NA,-1,2,1)

Comment: Show how you calculated `c (NA, NA, -1, -2,1, -1, - 1, -2, NA, NA, NA, -1,2,1)`. I don't understand how the calculation is done

Comment: First row output is NA because there is no previous row with Condition 1. Row 2 output is also NA for th same reason. Row 3 output is -1 because row 2 has condition 1 and gradient is 2-3 (Value of row 3 - value of Row 2). Row 4 output is -2 because the last previous row with condition 1 is still row 2 so gradient is 1-3 (value of row 4 - value of row 2). Row 5 output is 1 because the last row with condition = 1 is still row 2 so gradient is 4-3. Row 6 output is -1 because the last row with Condition 1 is now row 5 so gradient is 3-4.

Comment: Row 7 output is -1 because the last row with Condition 1 is now row 6 so gradient is 2-3.. Row 8 output is -2 because the last row with Condition 1 is still row 6 so gradient is 1-3.
So, generally speaking the pseudo-formula for each row is: gradient_of_i = 
Value_of_i  -  Value_of_last_row_with_Condition=1

Comment: I think i would need to just get the value of the last_row_with_condition=1 for each row i (by ID) as a new column first and then do a normal subtraction. I can't see how else it would be more efficient :)

Comment: Why do we need pipes here? `dt[Condition == 1, Value2 := Value, by = ID ][ ... ][ ... ][]` would work, too.

Comment: it's more convenient for me to read the code this way

Comment: shouldn't the second line .[, Value2 := shift(nafill(Value2, "locf"))] be also by by =.(ID) ?

possible correct answer:
dt[Condition == 1, Value2 := Value, by = ID] %>% 
  .[, Value2 := shift(nafill(Value2, "locf")), by = ID] %>% 
  .[ , Gradient2 := Value - Value2] %>% 
  .[, Value2 := NULL] %>% 
  .[]